# With Angularjs is there a best practice to update an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code works. I'm just curious if there is a better way to do this. For example, with only one or two lines.

```
ArtistDataService.update(entityData).then(function(response) {
    var artist = response.data;
    var artists = feedItem.event.artists;
    var artistToUpdate = $filter('filter')(artists, {_id: artist._id});
    var index = artists.indexOf(artistToUpdate[0]);
    artists[index] = artist;

    if (typeof feedItem.event.new === 'undefined') {
        $state.go('feedItem.event.eventEdit');
    } else {
        $state.go('feedItem.event.eventNew');
    }
});
```

Comment: is artists an array ? You could index them by _id and then just access directly to replace it, instead of filtering to get the index and then replace it. That's pure javascript. Something like `artists[artist._id]`, but that is if you can change how you are storing the data in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more performant way (since you're iterating twice, once to filter by id to a match and once to retrieve the record's index) is to simply use a good ol' fashioned for in loop.  Once you find the artist, update the artist in your array and break.

```
for (var i in artists) {
    if (artists[i]._id === artist._id) {
        artists[i] = artist;
        break; 
    }
}
```